# Read a .txt file from an anonymous FTP page?

Tags: java, android, ftp, text-files, anonymous

My goal is to to convert a .txt file on an FTP page to a simple `String` for easy manipulation.

The specific .txt file is here: ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt. It is an anonymous FTP page, so when I use my computer's browser, there's no need for a username or password.

I've tried incorporating different codes and tips from the following sources:

- [Reading Text File From Server on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922210/reading-text-file-from-server-on-android)
- http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/net-commons/download-file-from-ftp-server/
- [How to read a text file via FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036626/how-to-read-a-text-file-via-ftp)
- [Reading txt file from an ftp server and returning it from AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771733/reading-txt-file-from-an-ftp-server-and-returning-it-from-asynctask)
- [unable to read file from ftp in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009531/unable-to-read-file-from-ftp-in-android)
- [Howto do a simple ftp get file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053513/howto-do-a-simple-ftp-get-file-on-android)
- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073325/java-app-dev/java-ftp-client-libraries-reviewed.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html

None of what I've tried above helped. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

To be clear, all I want to do is to get the plain text from the posted .txt file. I have no interest in downloading said file onto my device's memory.

If you could provide me with a step-by-step explanation on how to do this, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: *I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.* Me too, because **you did not provide the code that you had tried** .. *step-by-step explanation on how to do this* you mean: write the code for you?

Comment: I already wrote in the question that I already incorporated code from the different sources. They're too varied to post on here, the question would be pages and pages long. I'm looking for something more unified from someone who knows better.

Comment: incorporated means copy&paste? then maybe you should change the server address ... seriously, lets take a look at the first link ... the code should works with only few (obvious) fixes .. first URL  should be `ftp://example.com/thefile.txt` (starts with `ftp` scheme)... and of course you would get NetworkOnMainThreadException (but it is not a problem since the question about this exception was asked many times here)

Comment: Alright... Let's tone down the attitude here. If you can't help, please move on. There's no need to troll someone who doesn't know how to do something you consider simple.

Comment: you are right, there is no need to troll stack overflow with such questions ... please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour ... you should rather ask something like : i did tried code from [link], my code lnow looks like [your code], now when i tried to run it on device/emulator, i'm getting such error/exception ...

Comment: Well... Thanks for the edit to your last comment. At least it's more constructive now. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I've got it. For those who are in the same boat, the step-by-step answer is below:

1. A lot of problems other users were encountering could be solved by having permissions for internet turned on in the manifest, but mine was a little more complicated. Turns out, the main trick is to not include `ftp://` in the address in `Java`.* Also, when you are entering an FTP site, make sure you enter via the **root** page, so my original page of ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt becomes: ftp.nasdaqtrader.com.
2. Make sure to download and include the right Apache Commons library in your project (here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi).
3. Connect to the root page:

   `FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();`

   `ftpClient.connect("ftp.nasdaqtrader.com");`
4. Login anonymously, in this case, both username and password are "anonymous". This might be the case with many FTP pages, but I can't be sure:

   `ftpClient.login("anonymous", "anonymous");`
5. Then, go to the correct directory (be careful about including/excluding the slashes):

   `ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/SymbolDirectory");`
6. Finally! You can now get the `InputStream` from the posted text file:

   `InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("nasdaqlisted.txt"));`
7. Then, convert the `InputStream` into `String` and manipulate as needed. There are many ways to do this. One of which can be found here: [How can I convert InputStream data to String in Android SOAP Webservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752919/how-can-i-convert-inputstream-data-to-string-in-android-soap-webservices)

*Source: [Android FTP connection Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186363/android-ftp-connection-failed)

Comment: The "anonymous" login was what I was missing, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, my dude. Frankly, I'm surprised my answer's still relevant after all these years.

Answer (score 0):

If you get "425 Unable to build data connection: Connection timed out" error, then after connecting to ftp server, I would recommend you to set the local mode to passive mode by the following statement.

```
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```